# Testing HTML and CSS for Email

Tags: html, css, django, email

I am building a Django application that needs to send out some Emails using HTML templates. The email templates use images as well as some variables from django context. Right now, every time I make an update to the inline css or html I send myself a new Email to check how the email looks in different Browsers/Applications. Is there a way I can preview the Email without having to send it to myself?
Just previewing the Email in the browser doesn't work as the CSS is always "interpreted" differently when I send it in an actual Email.

```
    <table cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#fff" border="0" style="width: 900px;">
        <a href="mailto:kontakt@schmerz-experts.de">
            <img style="width: 900px" src="cid:top.jpg" />
        </a>
    </table>

    <table cellpadding="12" bgcolor="#fff" border="0" style="width: 900px; margin-left: 0em; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;">VIELEN DANK.</p>

        <p>Sehr geehrte Patientin, Sehr geehrter Patient,</p>
        <p>Ihre Registrierung ist nun abgeschlossen. In Kürze erhalten Sie Ihren ersten Newsletter. </p>
        <p>Sollten Sie diesen innerhalb von 24 Stunden nicht erhalten, schauen Sie bitte auch in Ihrem Spam Ordner nach.
        </p>
        <p>Sollten Sie Fragen oder Anmerkungen haben, zögern Sie nicht uns zu kontaktieren.</p>
        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color: rgb(1,41,101)">
            <tr>
                <td
                    style="width: 350px;  padding: 16px 48px; background-color: rgb(1,41,101); text-align: center;font-weight: 700;">
                    <a class="button" style="color: #fff; width: 400px" href="mailto:kontakt@schmerz-experts.de">Kontakt
                        aufnehmen hier.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>Mit freundlichen Grüßen</p>
        <p>Ihr</p>
        <p>Schmerz-Spezialisten Team</p>
    </table>



Any help is greatly appreciated.

Example of an Email body:


Kind regards,
Andreas
```

Comment: Why not try sending for real?

Comment: Sending for real does work, but this means that for every change I want to make in the email, I must send it to see what it looks like. This is very tedious and takes quite a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common method among email developers is to use email screenshots services, like [Litmus](https://www.litmus.com), [Email on Acid](https://www.emailonacid.com) or [Testi.at](https://testi.at). But other than that, hand testing is still necessary and a proven way of doing things in the email world.

Comment: Thank you. I will go read up on the suggestions you have made. I thought there surely must be a better way, Writing HTML is not very much fun... I'll try to avoid this in the future ;)